# How to iteratively add tuple elements to a dataframe as new columns?

Tags: python, pandas, tuples, statsmodels, python-zip

I am using the `statsmodels.stats.multitest.multipletests` [function](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.multitest.multipletests.html)

to correct `p-values` I have stored in a dataframe:

```
p_value_df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [123456, 456789], "p-value": [0.098, 0.05]})

for _, row in p_value_df.iterrows():
    p_value = row["p-value"]
    print(p_value)
    results = multi.multipletests(
        p_value,
        alpha=0.05,
        method="bonferroni",
        maxiter=1,
        is_sorted=False,
        returnsorted=False,
    )
    print(results)
```

which looks like:
[image]

I would *really* like to add each of the elements of the `tuple` output as a new column in the `p_value_df` and am a bit stuck.

I've attempted to convert the results to a list and use `zip(*tuples_converted_to_list)` but as some of the values are `floats` this throws an error.

Additionally, I'd like to pull the `array` elements so that `array([False])` is just `False`.

Can anyone make any recommendations on a strategy to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a *listcomp* to make a nested list of the multitests, then pass it to the [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor and finally [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) it with the original `p_value_df` :

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.stats.multitest as multi

def fn(pval):
    return multi.multipletests(
        pval, alpha=0.05, method="bonferroni",
        maxiter=1, is_sorted=False, returnsorted=False,
    )

l = [
    [e[0] if isinstance(e, np.ndarray) and e.size == 1 else e
     for e in fn(pval)] for pval in p_value_df["p-value"]
]


cols = ["reject", "pvals_corrected", "alphacSidak", "alphacBonf"]

out = p_value_df.join(pd.DataFrame(l, columns=cols))
```

Output :

```
print(out)

       id  p-value  reject  pvals_corrected  alphacSidak  alphacBonf
0  123456    0.098   False            0.098         0.05        0.05
1  456789    0.050    True            0.050         0.05        0.05
```